# change default comment in nerd commenter

Tags: plugin-nerdcommenter

In `nerdcommenter`, the default comment is `/* */`.

I tried to change it to `#` for plain text as:

```
"NerdCommenter {{{
" Add spaces after comment delimiters by default
let g:NERDSpaceDelims = 1
" Use compact syntax for prettified multi-line comments
let g:NERDCompactSexyComs = 1
let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = { 'text': { 'left': '#','right': '' } }
"}}}
```

But this is still using default `/* */` style.

In `linux`, the file output is:

```
 file POSCAR
POSCAR: ASCII text
```

So, how I can change comment for such text file to `#`?

Comment: A more interesting output would be from Vim: `:set filetype?`

Comment: you are right...:set filetype is empty. I tried to change the empty filetype to text using:
`:autocmd BufNewFile * if &filetype == "" | set filetype=text | endif`
But this is not working

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Was incorrectly putting the custom delimiter option in my ~/.gvimrc. Worked when I put the custom delimiter setting in ~/.vimrc instead.